# SQLite Xamarin Duplicate Column Id Issue

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine (App.DEVICE_LOCAL_FOLDER, "database.db3");
            _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection (path);
            _database.CreateTableAsync<Setting> ().Wait ();
            _database.CreateTableAsync<Authentication> ().Wait ();
```

This code executes on App Startup for my Xamarin.Forms app, every time my app launches, I get "Message  "duplicate column name: setting_id" string". I erased the debugging device and launched from scratch just to make sure that a duplicate table or nothing like that wasn't getting created. My "Setting" model looks like this.

```
using SQLite;
namespace namespace
{
    public class Setting
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int setting_id { get; set; }
        public string field1 { get; set; } =
            "";
        public string field2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string emailOne { get; set; } = "";
        public string emailTwo { get; set; } = "";
        public string field3 { get; set; } = "";
        public string field4 { get; set; } = "";
        public Setting ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Using Xamarin.Forms version 2.2.0.45 and sqlite-net-pcl version 1.1.2. Currently I have only tested this on iOS and it always crashes on app startup, have not tested on Android.

Comment: Did you check on the Simulator? See [this forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65328/sqlite-duplicate-column-name-exception-on-device-but-not-on-simulator) for a possible solution

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I think that might be the solution, I do remember setting "Link All" as my assembly setting recently. I will confirm and get back. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gerald Versluis, the solution was to make sure that my assemblies were not all linked, once switched then linking to "SDK Assemblies Only" the problem was resolved.